# Object Detection with Bounding Boxes

Tags: python, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I've training dataset which has co-ordinates for the bounding boxes of the objects to be detected in an image. Now, I want to train my CNNs, that given an image they output the corresponding co-ordinates of the bounding boxes for the object detected in the complete image.

Training data format

```
ID              labels      x1  y1  x2      y2

144503924.jpg   Horse       38  12  234     142
```

Comment: This is too broad a question. There are many models/techniques for training networks. You should do some research about what models/techniques you want to use. e.g. you could use yolo: https://timebutt.github.io/static/how-to-train-yolov2-to-detect-custom-objects/

Comment: I want to use CNNs in keras to predict bounding boxes for the objects. Like YOLO, but they need data in VOC format. So, can it be done using just the co-ordinates somehow?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Given the training data as above, how to train CNNs so as to output the co-ordinates of the bounding box of the detected object in a test image.

Comment: It'll be easy to write a custom scripty (in python may be) to convert data from this format to VOC format easily. Then you can train using YOLO.